# User permissions inheritence

Tags: permissions, chmod

If an owner can read and write and the group can read and execute, can the owner execute the file? Do file permissions stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try:

```
$ touch test.sh
$ chmod 650 test.sh
$ ls -lh
-rw-r-x---  1 lorenzob lorenzob    0 Sep 10 00:01 test.sh
$ ./test.sh
bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

It seems that he can not!